# div like fixed but with position:absolute

Tags: javascript

I need something like this, but with `position:absolute` not `fixed`.

Is it possible with JavaScript to change top when user scrolling page?

```js
      var elementPosition = $('#div2').offset();
      var div1 = $('#div1');
      var main=$('#main');
      var spacer = $('#spacer');

  $(window).scroll(function(){
          if($(window).scrollTop() > elementPosition.top){
            var left = Math.ceil(div1.offset().left + div1.outerWidth()) + 'px';
     console.log(main.width(), div1.width())
              var width = main.width()  - div1.outerWidth() + 'px';
                $('#div2').css({
                 position: 'fixed',
                  left: left,
                  width: width
                });
                
          } else {
              $('#div2').css({
               'position':'static',
                width: 'auto'
              });
              
          }
  });
```

```css
body{
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
* { box-sizing: border-box;}
#main{
  width:80%;
  margin:0 auto;
}
#div1{
  width: 10%;
  border: solid 1px #000000;
  background-color: #0066CC;
  float: left;
}
#div2{
  height: 30px;
  border: solid 1px #000000;
  background-color: #66CC00;
}
#spacer {
  width: 90%;
  min-height:30px;
  float:left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div id="main">
    <div id="div1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet enim. Etiam ullamcorper. Suspendisse a pellentesque dui, non felis. Maecenas malesuada elit lectus felis, malesuada ultricies. Curabitur et ligula. Ut molestie a, ultricies porta urna. Vestibulum commodo volutpat a, convallis ac, laoreet enim. Phasellus fermentum in, dolor. Pellentesque facilisis. Nulla imperdiet sit amet magna. Vestibulum dapibus, mauris nec malesuada fames ac turpis velit, rhoncus eu, luctus et interdum adipiscing wisi. Aliquam erat ac ipsum. Integer aliquam purus. Quisque lorem tortor fringilla sed, vestibulum id, eleifend justo vel bibendum sapien massa ac turpis faucibus orci luctus non, consectetuer lobortis quis, varius in, purus. Integer ultrices posuere cubilia Curae, Nulla ipsum dolor lacus, suscipit adipiscing. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et ultrices volutpat. Nullam wisi ultricies a, gravida vitae, dapibus risus ante sodales lectus blandit eu, tempor diam pede cursus vitae, ultricies eu, faucibus quis, porttitor eros cursus lectus, pellentesque eget, bibendum a, gravida ullamcorper quam. Nullam viverra consectetuer. Quisque cursus et, porttitor risus. Aliquam sem. In hendrerit nulla quam nunc, accumsan congue. Lorem ipsum primis in nibh vel risus. Sed vel lectus. Ut sagittis, ipsum dolor quam.</div>
    <div id="spacer">
     <div id="div2">div2</div>
    </div>
   
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Try tracking the mouse scroll.

Comment: See this updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Arg0n/5n5MA/1174/

Comment: I strongly advise not to do this. Tracking the scroll in real time is a very resource heavy operation. Even if done correctly. There're plenty of things you can use that processing power for. Much better to find a way to accomplish it with position fixed. But if you do it anyway, at least use transforms, not top. And filter the scroll event, don't let it trigger your function every time it fires.

Comment: Also, this approach can become a great headache on mobile. especially on IOS 8-

Comment: If your plan is to use the approach in a more complex way - here's hoe it's done. http://scrollmagic.io/examples/

Answer (score 1):

Change to [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Arg0n/5n5MA/1174):

```
$('#div2').css({
  position: 'absolute',
  top: $(window).scrollTop(),
  left: left,
  width: width
});
```

Instead of (previous):

```
$('#div2').css({
  position: 'fixed',
  left: left,
  width: width
});
```